# How to show dictionary values on clicking a dictionary type row in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

My problem is, that I am fetching a PLIST which consists of String, boolean and Dictionary type data. My aim is to construct such a UI in which I am able to fetch this PLIST edit it and save the update back in the PLIST. So far, I am successful in fetching and saving the updates for string and boolean type, but I want that when I click on my Dictionary Type row, the keys of that dictionary should be populated as rows in my tableview and clicking on this rows the value should appear.

So what is the best way to show this dictionary type keys (i.e by adding the new rows on row click event or showing another tableview with new values of that dictionary?) or is there any other efficient way which I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [KOTree](https://github.com/adamhoracek/KOTree), which support multi-level data view support. It's for sure, you have to modify the [KOTreeTableViewCell](https://github.com/adamhoracek/KOTree/blob/master/KOTree/KOTreeTableViewCell.h) for your own `plist` related editing support.

here is a sample as which showing the item hierarchy, as it can be in your plist file format.

[image]